# Binarizing a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, image-processing

I have an image with a few bright pixels with the remaining ones very dark. The difference is in orders of magnitude.

I want to binarize this matrix (corresponding to the image) making all values zero besides the few bright ones.

The function Binarize does what I want but it accepts only an image as an input. So indeed I can use the plot of the matrix as input but that messes up things because the image includes the axis, labels etc...

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your matrix look like? `Binarize@Image[matrix]` could work.

Comment: @Pickett I chose to elaborate on that comment as there are unapparent details to be addressed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's a great answer. Very well written. +1.

Answer (score 6):

`Clip` seems perfectly suited:

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 100}];
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[Clip[mat, {threshold, threshold}, {0, 1}]],
 {threshold, 0, 10}
 ]
```

[image]

Here we use the form of [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) with three arguments:

```
Clip[mat, {threshold, threshold}, {0, 1}]
```

It takes everything below `threshold` and sets it to `0`, and takes everything above `threshold` and sets it to `1`. You can change both thresholds and the extreme values, eg

```
Clip[Range[10], {5, Infinity}, {0, 1}]
```

which sets everything below `5` to `0` and does nothing else (the `1` does nothing the way I wrote it).

Comment: `UnitStep[mat - threshold]` is easier and doesn't fail for elements of `mat` equal to `threshold`.

Answer (score 3):

As you note [`Binarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html) does just this:

> `Binarize[image,t]`
>   creates a binary image by replacing all values above `t` with 1 and others with 0.

Therefore you merely need to convert your data into an `Image`.  First some test data:

```
m = Array[Plus, {21, 21}, -10];
m // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Now we convert to an `Image`:

```
img = Image[m]
```

[image]

Do not worry that the data already appears binarized; it is still there:

> `Image[data]` by default allows any real number, but displays only values between 0 and 1.

We can still `Binarize` at any value within the range of the original array:

```
Binarize[img, #] & /@ {-18, -11, -4, 0, 4, 11, 18}
```

[image]

If you wish to recover the numeric data use [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageData.html):

```
Binarize[img, 11] // ImageData // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and fastest way to binarize a matrix directly without image conversions is with `UnitStep`:

```
matrixBinarize[mat_List, val_?NumericQ] := 
   UnitStep[Subtract[mat, val]]; (*Subtract is faster than mat - val*)
```

To automatically find a threshold like `Binarize` does:

```
matrixBinarize[mat_List] := matrixBinarize[mat, FindThreshold[mat]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately

```
Clip[mat, {threshold, threshold}, {0, 1}]
```

is not correct, because a value in "mat", which is exactly "threshold" will not be changed.
This just works for values < "threshold" and > "threshold".

Maybe this would be a solution for binarizing a matrix:

```
mat/.{x_/;x<threshold->0, x_/;x>=threshold->1}
```